# Error SessionNotCreatedException with NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 while running selenium remotedriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am running the following but getting the error

```
public class base
{
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[]  args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\code\\lib\\browser drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

        String URL = "http://www.google.com";
        String Node = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);


        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), cap);

        driver.navigate().to(URL);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }       
}
```

Error shown is as follows :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'RAJESHW10', ip: '169.254.3.253', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 316 milliseconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Can somebody please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create new Chrome remote session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600657/unable-to-create-new-chrome-remote-session)

Answer (score 0):

The error does gives us a hint about what is going wrong as follows :

- **`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService`** : **Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService** which means the new session wasn't initiated.
- **`Driver info: driver.version: unknown`** : **driver.version: unknown** means the **chromedriver** binary wasn't invoked at all.
- **`at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)`** : **sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)** which stems out from either of the following :

  **`java.lang.RuntimeException: exception in constructor`** : Occurance of this exception is unique to reflection. Normally, it is impossible to write code which ignores a checked exception as it would not compile at all.

  **`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`** : If an `InvocationTargetException` is thrown that means the method was invoked. This exception does not indicate a problem with the reflection package or its usage.

  **`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`** : An `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown if the constructor was passed an argument of the wrong type.

---

### Conclusion

From the above mentioned ponints it is pretty clear that the version of **`Selenium-Java`** client, **`JDK`**, **`ChromeDriver`** binary and **`Chrome`** are not compatible.

---

### Solution

The solution would be as follows :

- Update your **`JDK`** with the recent releases (**JDK 8u152**)
- Update your **`Selenium-Java`** client with the recent releases (**Selenium-Java v3.8.1**)
- Update your **`ChromeDriver`** binary with the recent releases (**ChromeDriver v2.34**)
- Update your **`ChromeDriver`** binary with the recent releases (**Chrome v63.0**)

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following and retry.

Ensure that the path `C:\\code\\lib\\browser drivers\\chromedriver.exe` is added to your `%PATH%` variable on the machine in which you are running the node. This would ensure that the selenium uber jar can find the location of the chromedriver binary.

> **System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\code\lib\browser drivers\chromedriver.exe");**

This mechanism should be only used when you are doing

`ChromeDriver driver = ChromeDriver()`

Since you are working with a selenium grid, you are dealing with multiple JVMs here.

`System.setProperty()` will affect only the current JVM (which in this case is your tests), but the actual browser gets spun off in a different JVM (the one that is running the selenium node).