# Exception "Was passed main parameter 'webdriver' but no main parameter was defined Error while creating note

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, virtual-machine, selenium-grid

I have gone through the video deeply and tried it but I am struck, please help.

- 1) I tried the code but i getting error of:

  > org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
  >   service: EdgeDriverService

[Errors Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SUzb.png)

So then later I found that there is a change to create a node for this error so i tried to create node by :

```
java -Dwebdriver.edge.driver=C:\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe -jar C:\selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role node webdriver -hub  http://10.144.102.48:4444/grid/register -port 5566
```

and also:

```
java -Dwebdriver.edge.driver=C:\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe -jar C:\selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role node webdriver -hub
```

Note: I am using a new VM with different IP address and I have downloaded `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe` and `C:\selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1` in the fresh VM.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRoRf.png)

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based HTML and code trials.

Comment: See this QA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068189/error-while-running-selenium-remotedriver/48079731#48079731

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your startup command for the node.

Valid values for role are either `hub` (To start the hub) (or) `node` (to start the JVM in the node mode) and no value which causes the JVM to come up in a standalone mode.

You provided

> java -Dwebdriver.edge.driver=C:\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe -jar C:\selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role node webdriver -hub  http://10.144.102.48:4444/grid/register -port 5566

Please have this changed to

`java -Dwebdriver.edge.driver=C:\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe -jar C:\selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role node -hub  http://10.144.102.48:4444/grid/register -port 5566`

Notice that the role has been specified as just `node` and not as `node webdriver` (which you have provided)

On a side note, I would encourage you to have the `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe` binary available as part of your `%PATH%` variable. Its only a one time activity and so it wont need you to keep passing in the path to it via the JVM argument.

Comment: NOw i am getting
 Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'

Comment: Please let us know what you did to get that exception and where are you seeing this exception.