# " org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException" for selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to run script to another vm but it give me following error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'BDQCC3', ip: '10.132.48.16', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown"
```

MY code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException 
 {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver;
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.132.48.16:5566/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());  
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception "Was passed main parameter 'webdriver' but no main parameter was defined Error while creating note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097238/exception-was-passed-main-parameter-webdriver-but-no-main-parameter-was-defin)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the command executed on grid node (10.132.48.16) to register to grid hub(10.132.48.16) is not correct. I doubt the command missed the option: `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=` to sepecify the path of chromedriver.

Register commmand example:

```
java -jar %~dp0\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig node.json -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=%~dp0\chromedriver.exe
```

login to the grid node `10.132.48.16`, stop the register process and check the register command is correct, also please put the command at here to help us to resovle the problem.