# Error after starting Selenium with chromedriver on debian 8

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, debian, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium with Google Chrome.
It works perfektly on my computer but it won't run on my Debian 8 64 bit server. But on the server I get get with the following code this error.

```
root@vps:/opt/SupportBot# java -jar /opt/web/googletest.jar
Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c) on port 14684
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c),platform=Linux 2.6.32-042stab127.2 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 147 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:14.666Z'
System info: host: 'vps.server.com', ip: 'X.XXX.XXX.XXX', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-042stab127.2', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
        at GoogleSearch.main(GoogleSearch.java:14)
```

Here is the code which I use for my windows PC and debian 8 server: https://pastebin.com/auyNbi28

*Used Software:*
 - Selenium version 3.8.1
 - ChromeDriver 2.34
 - Debian 8

**Update**:
Thanks C-Otto Now I'm getting ahead!
I've found out that the problem becaus chrome wasn't installed.
But I get now *this error in a loop*:

`Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c) on port 2783 Only local connections are allowed. [0.748][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error, errno=97: Address family not supported by protocol (97)`

Comment: Do you have Chrome on your server?

Comment: I have only downloaded the chromedriver from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads and put it into /opt/web and ajusted the right to execute it.

Comment: You also need Chrome, that's what the chromedriver is missing.

Comment: Now I'm getting ahead!
But I get now this error:
`Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c) on port 2783
Only local connections are allowed.
[0.748][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error, errno=97: Address family not supported by protocol (97)
`

Answer (score 0):

The first error which you were seeing was :

```
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

The main reason for the error is either of the following :

- **`java.lang.RuntimeException: exception in constructor`**
- **`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`**
- **`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`**

You can find a detailed discussion about the mentioned points in this [**`Answer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068189/error-sessionnotcreatedexception-with-nativeconstructoraccessorimpl-newinstance0/48079731#48079731).

The second error which you were seeing is :

```
[SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error, errno=97: Address family not supported by protocol (97)
```

The most common reason for this error is the mis-configuration in **`/etc/hosts`** file. Ensure that the entries in **`/etc/hosts`** are proper as follows :

```
....
---   127.0.0.1       localhost.domain               localhost
+++   127.0.0.1       localhost               localhost
```

But generally the **`CreatePlatformSocket()`** errors are likely from the **`IPv6`** probing in **`host_resolver_impl.cc`**.

[**`Issue#700347`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=700347) clearly mentions **Chrome doesn't support Linux kernels without IPv6 support**. There's a list of supported Linux distributions under `See system requirements` here:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95346?hl=en&ref_topic=3227046

This crash have been reported to Chromium and is being tracked [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706669).